# Amount of phytoestrogens in processed soy like tofu

Tags: endocrinology, soy

Does anyone know the amount of phytoestrogens like genistein in for example cooked soy, tofu, tempeh etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Below are the amounts of phytoestrogens content calculated from results of several analyses.

**DAIDZEIN**

1. Tofu - 76µg/g
2. Soy sauce - 8µg/g
3. Soy milk - 18µg/g
4. Tempeh - 190µg/g
5. Soy hot dog, tempeh burger - 49µg/g

**GENISTEIN**

1. Tofu - 166µg/g
2. Soy sauce - 5µg/g
3. Soy milk - 26µg/g
4. Tempeh - 320µg/g
5. Soy hot dog, tempeh burger - 139µg/g

For more info, visit:
http://extoxnet.orst.edu/faqs/natural/phytamt2.htm -